# Jaro-Winkler Distance Algorithm in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, jaro-winkler

Is there any LGPL or commercial-friendly licensed implementation of Jaro-Winkler distance in .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SimMetrics library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) appears to support Jaro-Winkler, and there's a .NET version available for download.

Unfortunately it's licensed under the GPL, but maybe the authors would be amenable to giving/selling you a commercial license.

*(NB: I haven't used this library myself, and know absolutely nothing about it.)*

Comment: Yeah, actually I've just tried it. Quite nice although GPL seems to be the problem. I might get in touch with the developers (.NET + Java dewvelopers :) it's a port) but I think I'll end up writing it by myself.

Comment: GPL is okay as a side-by-side with proprietary programs, meaning don't link against the library, but `popen` a GPLed executable and pass data back and forth that way.  Your program can still retain its proprietary license that way.  May or may not be suitable for your application.  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a public domain version in F#.  You can access it here: http://fssnip.net/2M