# Are there any string comparison alogrithms out there that are "better" than Levenshtein Distance?

Tags: .net, algorithm, string-comparison

I have been using it for a project I am working on, but some of the results aren't what I would choose.  For example:

When "Date" is compared to

1. "State" it has a lev distance of 2
2. "Today's Date" it has a lev distance of 9

This is what we would expect from the algorithm of course, but I'm curious if anyone knows of something out there that will give a closer match to any compared strings that have an exact match of the source string (Date)?  Meaning that "Today's Date" would have a higher ranking because it has "Date" in it.

Bonus points if you can find a .NET library that implements this.

Comment: What kind of Bonus points we talking?

Comment: @Scrum, I'll come wash your car.

Comment: @Lie, I thought I did.  Did you read the question or just the title?  Take a look at the second to last paragraph for an explanation on what I mean by "better"

Comment: You can simply word-match the string and modify it's ranking according to the results?
Also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510593/jaro-winkler-distance-algorithm-in-net

Comment: @Abe Miessler: giving one example is not sufficient, you should clearly define why a string should be considered closer match than another; or if you do not know that, can you explain what problems you are trying to solve? Levenshtein Edit Distance gives you the minimum number of single-character transformations (insert, delete, and change) required to transform one string to another string. It is "best" in one sense, but obviously is not what you're looking for.

Comment: You could for instance take the minimum of the Levenshtein distances of your word against multiple synonyms. For instance {"date","today's date","date of today", ...}. It could potentially be a lot of work to define synonyms if you need to match many different words, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's meant for you to tokenize the word before employing Levenshtein. As an alternative there is [Jaro-Winker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) distance too.

There's a .net library [SimMetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) which seems to cover [a few alternatives](http://staffwww.dcs.shef.ac.uk/people/S.Chapman/stringmetrics.html).

Comment: Interesting, so you're saying compare each individual word in the compared value?  Would I then use the lowest score from any of the words in the compared value?

Comment: @Abe - it would depend on the problem whether comparing each token and selecting the lowest match is appropriate.  Essentially doing this amounts to a fuzzy "contains" search.  I do this when comparing building names for campus buildings where it seems natural that a person would enter just the main part of the name but I would want to match based on the full name.  What I do is tokenize both the source and target strings, find the lowest distances for each token in the source to each target token, and sum them.

Comment: It depends on your application, if you want to use it to provide spelling suggestions for one or more words I think you should compare them individually; and the same goes for if you wish to see the likelihood of word `a` being in sentence `b`. But as I said, it depends on what you need the distance for.

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted to find [Longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)?

Answer (score 0):

To do it properly you need some context of the use

If you trying to do an address lookup then "Nosuch STREET" might have a perfect match of "Nosuch ROAD", or in a no-fly list you want all 20 spelling of Gadaffi to match.

if you are trying to analyse how much a piece of historic text has changed with copying then you need a different algorith,